# How do I add all of the items from a list to a variable?

Tags: python

I'm a complete beginner in Python and have come up against a problem that I can't solve. I have a variable called `body` which I am passing into a function to send in an email. I then have a list named `items` which I want to put in the body of the mail.

My code looks like this:

```
body = "The following items are in the list:"
```

How do I append all of the items in `items` list onto the end of the string in the `body` variable?

Comment: For future questions, it would be nice to show what you have done so far and show that you already attempted to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
body = str("The following items are in the list: ")
items = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]  # list of strings
for i in items:
    body = body.__add__(i + ",")
print(body)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I hadn't learned about magic methods yet!

Comment: This is not even valid python code (Python uses `#` for comments, not `//`)

Comment: Why use `__add__` instead of the `+` operator to concatenate?

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ['first', 'second']
body = "The following items are in the list:"

print(body + ' ' + ' '.join(lst))
```

output:

```
The following items are in the list: first second
```

`some_string.join(list)` returns a string with `some_string` added between all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's string formatting to accomplish this:

```
body = "The following items are in the list:"
items = ["first", "second", "third"]
body = "{} {}.".format(body, ' '.join(items))
```

Will return

```
'The following items are in the list: first second third.'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# choose a delimiter for items in the list
delimiter = ' '

# join each item in the list separated by the delimiter
items_str = delimiter.join(str(i) for i in items)

body = "The following items are in the list: {}".format(item_str)
```